# The transport failed to connect to the server - CDO.Message - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, smtp, cdo.message

I have a VB.net Application running on the server which will be sending emails close to 200 everyday.  Following is my coding:

```
Dim objNewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
                  objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
                    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "localhost"
                    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
                    objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update()

                    objNewMail.From = mailFrom
                    objNewMail.To = mailTO
                    objNewMail.CC = mailCC
                    objNewMail.bcc = mailBCC

                    objNewMail.Subject = mailSubject
                    objNewMail.HTMLBody = content
                    objNewMail.Send()

                    objNewMail = Nothing
```

The above codes runs inside a loop.  The above code runs quite well without any issues.  But once or twice a month, i get the following error message and application stops.

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040213): The transport failed to connect to the server.**

Can anybody help me fixing this issue or i m also open for any other better and advanced approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to wrap the .Send() call in a Try...Catch and retry after a few seconds if it fails.

CDO appears to have been deprecated in favour of System.Net.Mail. There is a site with a comprehensive FAQ for it at [www.systemnetmail.com/](http://www.systemnetmail.com/) , although I would be looking in the event logs for an occassional error like that.

Is there anything else coincident with the error, for example the server has just rebooted?